# Laravel migration could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, mysql-connector

I have this error when i try to make `php artisan migrate`

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lsapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +34 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I have already create my database on phpmyadmin. here is the configuration of my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lsapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and here the coonfiguration of mysql in my config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lsapp'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ]
```

help me solve that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **php.ini** configuration file uncomment the extension, remove `;` :

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

If you're on **Linux** make it:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then restart the server.

*If this isn't working for you, you may need to install **pdo_mysql** extension into your php library.*

Comment: I removed the ```;``` in my /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini file but it is doing the same thing

Comment: I have two versions of php in my computer and I have modified php.ini in the two folder(7.2 and 7.3)  but it is doing the same thing

Comment: @Etali after modify the php.ini file you need to restart your server/apache

Comment: the problem was that i had edited the wrong php.ini file, the php.ini file i needed to edit was in my server location (/ opt / lampp / etc) thank you for your help

Comment: `sudo apt install php-mysql`  this helped me after removing php and reinstalling php.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you are using two or more versions of php. So you better do:

`sudo apt install php-mysql`

This way you can be sure `pdo_mysql` extension is installed on each version.

After this just restart apache2: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with this setup: Laravel, composer, nginx, mariadb, and php8 on Rocky Linux 8. When running `php artisan migrate`, I got the error that mysql could not find the driver. I installed `php-mysql` and then everything worked.

```
sudo dnf install php-mysql -y
```

or

```
sudo yum install php-mysql y
```

then

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Good luck and hope this helps.

Failing
[image]

Working
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check if `pdo_mysql` extension is activated in `php.ini` file.